# Oliver Black is murdered

Tags: situation

Billionaire Oliver Black is shot in his own mansion along with an Asian businessman, Mr. Lee. Lee was visiting Oliver for the very first time to discuss an Asian venture. Both were shot at close range in an office inside the mansion. At the hospital, Mr. Black was pronounced dead while Lee was still clinging to life.

A police officer tried to talk to Lee before he went for a surgery. The officer then called Detective Kelly who was on his way to the crime scene.

"What did Mr. Lee say?", asked Kelly.

"I could only make out a couple of words. Something about the family heirs", said the officer.

Kelly entered the mansion and found four adults at the scene: Oliver's wife, his son, his daughter, and his brother. Kelly talked to them at length and concluded:

1. They were all at the mansion during the shooting
2. They all said they were nowhere near the office and did not see the crime.
3. They all were legitimate heirs to Mr. Black's fortune. A call to Oliver's lawyer confirmed that all four were in the will.
4. No other people were there except for these four.

Kelly thought of something and called the police officer again.

"What were Mr. Lee's exact two words?", he asked.

Based on the reply, Kelly arrested Oliver's brother for the murder.

Why?

Answer (score 4):

Mr Lee actually said

> Family Hair

> Both Oliver and his brother have black hair (matching the family name), while his son and daughter have inheritied his wife's hair colour (blond, maybe?)

Answer (score 4):

The officer reported that Mr. Lee's exact two words were

> **blood heir**

Kelly realized that Mr. Lee was actually saying

> **brother**
>  (Native speakers of East Asian languages sometimes have trouble pronouncing the English phonemes /ɹ/ (r) and /ð/ (th))

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that

> It wasn't two words Mr Lee said, it was one - **familiars**

Reasoning

> A familiar is another word for a doppelgänger - see Pierre A. Riffard's definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familiar). Mr Lee uses this word to describe Oliver Black and his brother as they are identical twins.

Answer (score 0):

I feel I am making a huge assumption here however:

> The priority for inheritance in Asian  cultures includes Brothers and Sisters as natural heirs.
>  In western cultures Siblings typically need to be written into the will to receive an inheritance from their brother in this case.

I do not follow how this proves who the guilty party was but I do believe Mr. Lee's assumption along these lines is being used to identify the suspect.